# Github Import error while importing SVN Repository

Tags: git, github, svn, visualsvn-server

I am trying to import SVN Repository into github using github importer and the repository path is like "https://172.10.2.2./svn/XYZRepo/".

**Error :**
We can't import from https://172.10.2.2./svn/XYZRepo/. Please check the URL and try again.

What could be the reasons?any Solutions,suggestions accepted.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Because the IP is not [accessible](http://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/172.10.2.2).

Comment: But I am able to clone using "git svn clone https://172.10.2.2./svn/XYZRepo/ " command.

Comment: Because the address is accessible from your network. But it's cut from the outside.

Comment: But I am Connected to the remote VPN, If I am trying to ping the above URL from my local I am not able to do it ,But I am able to clone from the above path what could be the problem?

Comment: ... and there is a typo in the URL.

Comment: It is possible the administrator disabled ping response at the firewall level and that's why you were unable to ping.